# How to handle a stored procedure with Input and Output parameter in a cursor?

Tags: sql, t-sql, stored-procedures, cursor

I have a `stored procedure` that holds a query giving me a value as varchar (`output`) for an employee id (`input`).

My cursor holds a list of employee id and I want to loop the stored procedure and print the values for each employee id.

That is what I have tried so far:

```
DECLARE @MyCursor as CURSOR
DECLARE @InputPar as int
DECLARE @OutputPar as varchar(30)

SET @MyCursor = CURSOR FOR <query>

Open @MyCursor;
FETCH NEXT FROM @MyCursor INTO @InputPar

BEGIN
WHILE @@FETCH_STATUS = 0
Exec dbo.mySP @InputPar, @OutputPar Output
Print @OutputPar
FETCH NEXT FROM @MyCursor INTO @InputPar
END
CLOSE @MyCursor;
DEALLOCATE @MyCursor;
```

The error I get at the moment is `Must declare the scalar variable "@QutputPar".` The variable is declared above so I do not see where the problem is. Could anyone help me get my code running?

Answer (score 0):

reason why you doing through cursor is not known,it can be replaced (99% of time) with a set based operation..Reason why you are not getting values is you are not reading output value correctly..

Below is the way to do

```
   Declare @var int/varchar--delcare datatype as per u r need
    Exec dbo.mySP @InputPar, @var Output

    Print @var
```

Comment: could you tell me what @b is?

Comment: that it is your parameter,you can also just use @var

Comment: Sorry, but I do not see any difference to my line: Exec dbo.mySP '@InputPar', '@OutputPar' Output. But maybe I am blind.

Comment: You should Declare output variable first

Comment: where is this declared `Qutput_Strings`

Comment: I thought I would have declared it here: DECLARE @OutputPar as varchar(30)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/123849/discussion-between-thegameiswar-and-ruedi).

Comment: Can you try declaring the way i did and check once

Answer (score 0):

```
DECLARE @InputPar as int
DECLARE @OutputPar as varchar(30)
declare MyCursor cursor for <your query here>
Open MyCursor;
FETCH NEXT FROM MyCursor INTO @InputPar

Exec dbo.mySP @InputPar, @OutputPar Output
Print @OutputPar

CLOSE MyCursor;
DEALLOCATE MyCursor;
```